# Get unknown number of parameter from input

Tags: c++, scanf

When I use scanf(), I need to know how many parameters I will get from the client.
For example, `scanf("%d%d", &n1, &n2);`

What if I don't know the exact number of input parameters?

In the instance above, it's possible that when the client input an invalid number, and I want to interrupt the process without getting the rest of  the parameters.

It's OK if you can recommend me some other functions in C/C++ to deal with this problem.

Comment: Use `std::cin >> n1 >> n2`

Comment: How about calling `scanf()` in a loop?

Comment: In c++ it's probably better to use `std::cin` for reading input. Though for either cases you should use a loop and check the input stream state after reading the input.

Comment: @Unda That's still fixed at reading 2 variables, nothing gained.

Comment: You're doing C++ - don't use `scanf` !!!

Comment: But isn't it faster to use scanf() than use iostream? @Sean

Comment: @Jutta - You're doing console IO, I wouldn't worry about the performance. Plus, think of the type safety that `iostream` gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing I can think of in c++:

```
std::vector<int> allParams;
int num;
while(std::cin >> num) {
    allParams.push_back(num);
}
```

---

Similar solution using `scanf()`:

```
std::vector<int> allParams;
int num;
while(scanf("%d", &num) != EOF) {
    allParams.push_back(num);
}
```